# Deploying remote docker container (FastAPI) on ubuntu server but got "refused to connect" on port 3000

Tags: docker, ubuntu, server, port, fastapi

### Problem

Currently I'm trying to made an API for connecting frontend and backend database on an Ubuntu server(Btw all operations are done by ssh into the server remotely, so port 22 seems ok). I'v wrapped it in an container and deployed on Ubuntu, exposing port 3000 -> 80/tcp, and set the ufw allow for port 3000 in Ubuntu, and check for the route table settings like below:

#### Ubuntu

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

#### docker container

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo docker container ls
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS       PORTS                                   NAMES
85842c4343f5   813       "uvicorn main:app --…"   3 weeks ago   Up 3 weeks   0.0.0.0:3000->80/tcp, :::3000->80/tcp   zen_curran
```

#### ufw settings

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
3000                       ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
3000/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
3000 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
3000/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

#### ip route

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ip route show
default via 192.168.50.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp src 192.168.50.17 metric 600
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1
192.168.50.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.50.17
192.168.50.1 dev wlan0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.50.17 metric 600
```

#### iptables

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo iptables -t nat -nL
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0           !127.0.0.0/8          ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  172.17.0.0/16        0.0.0.0/0
MASQUERADE  tcp  --  172.17.0.2           172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:80

Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3000 to:172.17.0.2:80
```

So, the details on the Ubuntu server are just like above, but I still can't reach the API with URL http://122.116.234.117:3000/docs (since this is the FastAPI Swagger UI link)

I'v done curl command locally and remotely and got the below result:

locally (in the server) :

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ curl 0.0.0.0:3000/docs

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swagger-ui-dist@4/swagger-ui.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/img/favicon.png">
    <title>FastAPI - Swagger UI</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="swagger-ui">
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swagger-ui-dist@4/swagger-ui-bundle.js"></script>
    <!-- `SwaggerUIBundle` is now available on the page -->
    <script>
    const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
        url: '/openapi.json',
    "dom_id": "#swagger-ui",
"layout": "BaseLayout",
"deepLinking": true,
"showExtensions": true,
"showCommonExtensions": true,
oauth2RedirectUrl: window.location.origin + '/docs/oauth2-redirect',
    presets: [
        SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
        SwaggerUIBundle.SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
        ],
    })
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

remote (outside the server) :

```
❯ curl 122.116.234.117:3000/docs
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 122.116.234.117 port 3000 after 10 ms: Connection refused
```

So it seems that route table and network settings are all working, but I still can't reach the URL, I'm wondering what might seems to be the problem? Is there anything I didn't notice or anything strange in those logs?

p.s. This is the image of the container in the server : https://hub.docker.com/r/lyz07/koala

Truly have been stuck here for weeks and can't find out with a solution...

Comment: It looks like your local address is `192.168.50.17`. What is the relation between that address and `122.116.234.117`?

Comment: Seems like it is use for URL redirection, I curl it in the server
this is what I get :   
`ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ curl 192.168.50.1
<HTML><HEAD><script>top.location.href='/Main_Login.asp';</script> 
</HEAD></HTML>`